# Opencart module error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'model' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php

Tags: php, module, opencart

I'm trying to create a module to automatically import products from an external database into Opencart's database.

I followed all the available documentation to build the module. Created controller, view, language files. I didn't create a model file because I'm using the opencarts models.

Within my controller `opencart/admin/controller/extension/module/auto_product_import.php`

I'm starting a connection with my external database.

Then I execute the query to retrieve all the products and their data (prices, description, etc).

After that, I create an array to suit the needs of opencart models and populate it with my newly retrieved data :

```php
    for ($i=0; $i < 1; $i++) { 
                $products_data_array[] = array(
                    'product_description' => array(
                        'name' => strval($results['product_CODE'][$i]),
                        'meta_description' => strval($results['DESCR'][$i]),
                        'meta_keyword' => strval($results['product_CODE'][$i]),
                        'description' => strval($results['DESCR'][$i]),
                        'tag' => strval($results['CODCODE'][$i]),
                    ),
                    'custom_id' => $results['custom_ID'][$i],
                    'model' => $results['product_CODE'][$i], 
                    'sku' => '', 
                    'upc' => '', 
                    'ean' => '', 
                    'jan' => '', 
                    'isbn' => '', 
                    'mpn' => '', 
                    'location' => '', 
                    'price' => $results['PRICE'][$i], 
                    'tax_class_id' => '',
                    'quantity' => '',
                    'minimum' => '',
                    'subtract' => '',
                    'stock_status_id' => '5',
                    'shipping' => '',
                    'keyword' => '', 
                    'image' => '',
                    'date_available' => '',
                    'length' => '',
                    'width' => '',
                    'height' => '',
                    'length_class_id' => '',
                    'weight' => strval($results['weight'][$i]),
                    'weight_class_id' => '',
                    'status' => '1',
                    'sort_order' => '',
                    'manufacturer' => $brand, 
                    'manufacturer_id' => '', 
                    'category' => strval($results['category'][$i]), 
                    'filter' => '', 
                    'product_store' => array(
                        '0' => 0
                    ),
                    'download' => '',
                    'related' => '',
                    'product_attribute' => array(
                        '0' => array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'attribute_id' => '', 
                            'product_attribute_description' => array(
                                '1' => array(
                                        'text' => "first language content"
                                )
                            )
                        )
    
                    ),
                    'option' => '',
                    'points' => '',
                    'product_reward' => array(
                        '1' => array(
                            'points' => ''
                        )
                    ),
                    'product_layout' => array(
                        '0' => array(
                                'layout_id' => '' 
                        )
                    )
                );
```

**Note**: use for loop with 1 iteration for testing purposes

**Note**: some items of the opencart's array are empty cause I don't have data to import for them

Then I load the opencart's model to add products:

```php
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

And then I import the products using:

```php
$this->model_catalog_product->addProduct($products_data_array);
```

When I load my module I get the following messages:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'model' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'custom_id' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'sku' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'upc' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'ean' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'jan' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'isbn' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'mpn' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'location' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'quantity' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'minimum' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'subtract' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'stock_status_id' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'date_available' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'manufacturer_id' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'shipping' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'price' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'points' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'weight' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'weight_class_id' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'length' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'length_class_id' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'status' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'tax_class_id' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'sort_order' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 4
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'product_description' in opencart/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 12

I tried to modify the `product.php` model but I had no luck. :(

Also it inserts a row with the new product but all the fields are empty it only gets and id.

I even checked my new array just in case. But I found no issues.

Does anyone know what is wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Which OC version are you working on?

Comment: Version 3.0.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after I restructured the array. The sub-array should have a child array with language_id as a key inside of it.

The functional array should be stuctured like this:

```php
$products_data_array[] = array(

                'product_description' => array(
                    '0' => array(
                        'name' => $name,
                        'meta_description' => $meta_description,
                        'meta_title' => $meta_title,
                        'meta_keyword' => $meta_keyword,
                        'description' => $description,
                        'tag' => $tag,
                    )
                ),
                'mciid' => $mciid,
                'model' => $model, 
                'sku' => '', 
                'upc' => '', 
                'ean' => '', 
                'jan' => '', 
                'isbn' => '', 
                'mpn' => '', 
                'location' => '', 
                'price' => $price, 
                'tax_class_id' => '',
                'quantity' => '',
                'minimum' => '',
                'subtract' => '',
                'stock_status_id' => '5',
                'shipping' => '',
                'keyword' => '', 
                'image' => '',
                'date_available' => '',
                'length' => '',
                'width' => '',
                'height' => '',
                'length_class_id' => '',
                'weight' => $weight,
                'weight_class_id' => '',
                'status' => '1',
                'sort_order' => '',
                'manufacturer' => $brand, 
                'manufacturer_id' => '111', 
                'category' => $category, 
                'filter' => '', 
                'product_store' => array(
                    '0' => 0
                ),
                'download' => '',
                'related' => '',
                'product_attribute' => array(
                    '0' => array(
                        'name' => '',
                        'attribute_id' => '', 
                        'product_attribute_description' => array(
                            '1' => array(
                                    'text' => "first language content"
                            )
                        )
                    )

                ),
                'option' => '',
                'points' => '',
                'product_reward' => array(
                    '1' => array(
                        'points' => ''
                    )
                ),
                'product_layout' => array(
                    '0' => array(
                            'layout_id' => '2' 
                    )
                )
            );
```

Note: This array is functional on Version 3.0.3.8 of Opencart.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like addProduct() is for adding 1 product at a time and you're sending the entire array of products.

Try this:

```
foreach ($products_data_array as $product) {
    $this->model_catalog_product->addProduct($product);
}
```

Comment: Saddly it throws the same error

Comment: What are the lines of code 1-4+ in product.php?